# The expansion parameter must have a tuple type or be passed to the rest parameter

Tags: typescript

```
    function test(a: number, b: number, c: number) {}
    function test1() {}

    const o = { test, test1 };

    type Type = typeof o;

    function test2<K extends keyof Type>(key: K, ...args: Parameters<Type[K]>) {
      const fn: Type[K] = o[key];
      fn(...args);
      // err：The expansion parameter must have a tuple type or be passed to the rest parameter.
    }
```

this `fn(...args);` err: The expansion parameter must have a tuple type or be passed to the rest parameter.

What do I need to do?

Comment: It depends; if you're just trying to move forward then a type assertion like `(fn as any)` will get you going. If you're trying to have the compiler actually follow your logic and verify type safety you need to refactor the type of `o` as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJBb6W) for a demo.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: In actual development, 'o' is a set of functions in an NPM package that I cannot modify

Comment: I didn't modify `o`, I just assigned it to a new variable with a more TS-friendly type. Could you double check?

Comment: Just finished reading, your answer has solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: So then I’ll post an actual answer (not just comments) when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to move past the error as quickly as possible, you can use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to disable type checking of `fn`:

```
function test2<K extends keyof Type>(key: K, ...args: Parameters<Type[K]>) {
    // TS can't figure out the relationship, just mark fn as any
    const fn: any = o[key];
    fn(...args); // okay
}
```

Of course you're paying for the convenience by completely giving up on compiler-verified type safety. When using `any` or [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) you take the responsibility for type checking away from the compiler.

---

If, on the other hand, you want the compiler to understand the logic of what you're doing, then you'll need to refactor the type of `o` to something that actually represents it at the type level.  The type checker doesn't understand that `Parameters<Type[K]>` is an appropriate argument for a function of type `Type[K]`.  The type `Type[K]` is seen as being constrained to a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions, as opposed to a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type. The type checker can't abstract over the form `{ test(a: number, b: number, c: number): void; test2(): void }` to anything useful.  The type `Parameters<Type[K]>` is a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and such types are notoriously inscrutable to the compiler. It doesn't ascribe meaning to the identifier "`Parameters`", nor can it reason abstractly to deduce that.

This general issue of TypeScript being unable to deduce abstract correlations among data structure is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), where it's phrased in terms of correlated *unions*.  And the supported solution and recommended approach to this is to refactor to a particular form of generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  This is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

For the example code here, the requisite refactoring looks like

```
function test3<K extends keyof Type>(key: K, ...args: Parameters<Type[K]>) {
    const _o: { [P in keyof Type]: (...args: Parameters<Type[P]>) => void } = o;
    const fn = _o[key];
    fn(...args); // okay
}
```

Here we assign `o` to a new variable `_o` of the mapped type `{ [P in keyof Type]: (...args: Parameters<Type[P]>) => void }`.  That assignment succeeds because when given a non-generic value `o`, the compiler evaluates the type of `_o` completely and sees that they are structurally identical.

But even though they're structurally identical, they're represented in different forms. The mapped type explicitly captures the generic relationship between an arbitrary property of `_o` and its function shape.  Indexing into `_o` with `key` is seen not as a union of functions, but directly as a single function type, `(...args: Parameters<Type[K]>) => void`.  And this function type accepts `...args` easily.

So that's how TypeScript supports this sort of function while keeping some type safety guarantees.  This particular refactoring didn't take much effort or added code, but often such refactorings can make the code significantly less understandable to the human developers who need to maintain it.  It depends on your use case which of quick/easy/unsafe and slow/complex/safe is preferable.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OCAzNvW4-XN-ZIAv3A0HgtCQgZDOAJbDp3hAA)